# Neo4jClient : C# query to fetch collection with multiple columns

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

How one can fetch multiple columns data using neo4jClient -

For eq. the example shown on link

[Cyper query to fetch multiple column collection](https://dzone.com/articles/neo4j-collecting-multiple)

The sample shown above passes properties of event node for collection instead of complete event node.

The query I am constructing takes few properties from the event node and few properties from the relation.

For eq. The relation attribute "registerd_on" needs to be added.
So how to pass multiple properties for collection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very nice, but if you look at what is returned by doing a collection you get an array of arrays, but these arrays don't have properties as such, so you can only really parse them as `string`.

Using the `:play movies` dataset as a base:

```
var query = gc.Cypher
    .Match("(p:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-->(m:Movie)")
    .With("p, collect([m.title, m.released]) as collection")
    .Return((p, collection) => new
    {
        Person = p.As<Person>(),
        Collection  = Return.As<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>>("collection")

    });
```

where `Person` is :

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then access the data like so:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Person: {result.Person.name}");
    foreach (var collection in result.Collection)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{item}");
        }
    }
}
```

which is not nice :/

Comment: Thanks Chris.
Already figured out the answer from 
https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/issues/214